# Program Command Button to Run Formula on Column

Tags: excel, vba

I need help coming up with the vba coding to develop a button that will convert the number of questions a student answered correctly into a percentage out of the number of questions that were on the test.  It is a spreadsheet with two columns (A & B) with the number of questions to be entered into B2.  The students names are in A5:A24 and the number of questions they got correct will be from B5:B24.

For printing purposes, the spreadsheet needs to stay in two columns, which is why I am looking to come up with a button that will divide B5:B24 by B2 and then convert that into a percentage for each of the students in A5:A24, and put that answer back in B5:B24.  Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Use Evaluate:

```
Sub kkjkk()
    [B5:B24] = [B5:B24/B2]
End Sub
```